Polygon fallback handler contract
where can I find the source code of the fallback handler contract that is currently deployed on polygon mainnet?
https://polygonscan.com/address/0x75cf11467937ce3f2f357ce24ffc3dbf8fd5c226

This does not look like a Safe contract, as you can find all "official" deployments on this page: https://docs.safe.global/advanced/smart-account-supported-networks. Are you sure it was deployed by Safe? Best, Louis
